# Are there easier ways to excute model's layers in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Let's assume that I make a custom model by using *Keras subclassing API in Tensorflow 2.0* like below.

```
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    return self.d2(x)

model = MyModel()
```

If there aren't many layers, it's not that annoying to write 'def call' of the class.

All I need to do is just writing down 3~4 lines of layers like above.

But what if the number of layer increases like 50~60 or even higher?

Do I have to type all of these layers? Wouldn't there be a much better way I don't know?

I look forward to your answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't follow TF closely, but the last time I saw Keras, there was `Sequential`. Is it there no more?

Comment: @dedObed It still has `Sequential`. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop to create a number of layers at once, then call them using a for loop.

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import partial

x = tf.random.uniform((5, 2), 0, 1)

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    dense_layer = partial(tf.keras.layers.Dense, units=3, activation='relu')
    self.layer_list = [dense_layer(name=f'layer_{i}') for i in range(3)]
    self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

  def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
    for layer in self.layer_list:
        x = layer(x)
    x = self.out(x)
    return x

model = MyModel()
model.build(input_shape=(5, 2))
```

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x.name, model.layer_list)))
```

```
['layer_0', 'layer_1', 'layer_2']
```

```
model(x)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.51850706],
       [0.5285746 ],
       [0.51396513],
       [0.5171388 ],
       [0.50938624]], dtype=float32)>
```

Some architectures repeat themselves (e.g., a succession of convolutional layers and max pooling layers multiple times), so you can create function that return a number of layers, and then use a loop to create many of them. To avoid repeating everything, I used [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects), which creates a callable with default arguments.

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import partial

x = tf.random.uniform((5, 256, 256, 3), 0, 1)

def conv_block(units):
    conv = partial(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')
    pool = partial(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D, pool_size=(2, 2))
    layer_dict = {
        'conv1': conv(units),
        'pool1': pool(),
        'conv2': conv(units*2),
        'pool2': pool(),
        'conv3': conv(units*3)
    }
    return layer_dict

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.block_list = [conv_block(i) for i in range(1, 3)]
    self.flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

  def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
    for block in self.block_list:
        for layer in block.values():
            x = layer(x)
    x = self.flat(x)
    x = self.out(x)
    return x

model = MyModel()
model.build(input_shape=(5, 256, 256, 3))

model(x)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.48275623],
       [0.48887327],
       [0.49217385],
       [0.48883903],
       [0.48933515]], dtype=float32)>
```

As you can see, I generated this block twice:

```
model.layers
```

```
[<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x1b404f47b08>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x1b40be6cb48>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x1b40d6eab88>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D at 0x1b40be6cb08>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D at 0x1b40d6ddc08>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x1b40d6f2188>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x1b40d6f2bc8>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x1b40d6f0648>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D at 0x1b40d6f2748>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D at 0x1b40d6f01c8>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten at 0x1b40d6f8cc8>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x1b40d6ee248>]
```

Comment: It's little closer to the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Creating class in TF 2.0 makes it easier to compete with Pytorch and other deep learning framework. However, if your model is Sequential, stacking layers on top of each other, you can still apply it by this [example](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/).

For model that need to execute multiple output, parallel computing like SSD or YOLO, writing comprehensively like a class is better or you can use Model directly by passing multiple inputs and multiple outputs to the model ([example](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/))

Comment: but I suggest you should stick with the class inherit Model for further high level development

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: for higher model, you need to declare multiple and parallel model at once. When you writing sequential, it will be easy but too bulky. That is why Pytorch is very preferable. You should try it when you got time

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the advice again!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't see how this answers the question at all...

Comment: he just want to write the model in a simple pipeline, directly without classes and stuffs

Comment: The first sentences reads: _Let's assume that I make a custom model by using Keras subclassing API in Tensorflow 2.0 like below._

Comment: """If there aren't many layers, it's not that annoying to write 'def call' of the class.

All I need to do is just writing down 3~4 lines of layers like above.""", that is why I suggest him use sequential, which has bypassed the function call definition as he wants